Change color in python for all text
My goal is to use a command or anything else to change color for all text coming after the command. Something like this:
#Command to change color
change_color(red)

#Both outputs should be red
print("Hello world!")
print("Hi world")

change_color(green)

#Both outputs should be green
print("Hello world!")
print("Hi world")

I know i could use colorama or other methods but for now i didn't find a solution that works how i explained above. I want to do it like this because i need to change the output color for many lines of code.
I also tried using os.system('color a') for green or something like this, but it changed color to red and if i try another color it doesn't work as expected, i think it's for the dark theme i use in my ide or in windows.

This Python code utilizes ANSI escape codes to change the color of text:
   class TextColor:
    RESET = "\033[0m"
    RED = "\033[31m"
    GREEN = "\033[32m"
    YELLOW = "\033[33m"
    BLUE = "\033[34m"
    PURPLE = "\033[35m"
    CYAN = "\033[36m"
    WHITE = "\033[37m"

current_color = TextColor.RESET

def change_color(color):
    global current_color
    if color == "red":
        current_color = TextColor.RED
    elif color == "green":
        current_color = TextColor.GREEN
    elif color == "yellow":
        current_color = TextColor.YELLOW
    elif color == "blue":
        current_color = TextColor.BLUE
    elif color == "purple":
        current_color = TextColor.PURPLE
    elif color == "cyan":
        current_color = TextColor.CYAN
    elif color == "white":
        current_color = TextColor.WHITE
    else:
        print("Invalid color!")

def print_colored(text):
    print(current_color + text + TextColor.RESET)

# Usage example:
change_color("red")
print_colored("Hello world!")
print_colored("Hi world")

change_color("green")
print_colored("Hello world!")
print_colored("Hi world")

ANSI escape codes are a set of standardized codes that allow a programmer to style the output in console and text based applications.

I will use this option. Thanks

I was wandering what happens if in the function print_colored I print only current_color + text without text color.reset
